# Hide columns when cell is empty in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that has values in the second row.
I want each column that contains no values (=="") to be hidden.
[In this example, column G, J, K and L need to be hidden.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IipxCFCpcH7VQlpd_cbYsRqihF5eEatc3k5HxQ96HyU/edit?usp=sharing).
The script I tried is attached to the document.
I wrote it down here aswell:

```
 function hideEmptyCourses() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1,sheet.getLastColumn()); //start number Row, start      number Column, amount of rows , amount of columns 


//get the values to those Columns
var values = range.getValues();
Logger.log(values);

//go through every Column
for (var i=0; i==values.length; i++){

    //if column value is equal to empty  
    if(values[0][i] === ""){

    //hide that column
    sheet.hideColumn(i+1);   
    }   
}
}
```

Any help would be much apreaciated. It's probably something stupid, but I can't seem to get it working.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your for loop should be like this if you want to go through every column.

```
for (var i=0; i < values[0].length; i++){
```

Also you check only one row ? Below code uses a slighly different approach. Can you see if it works ?

```
function hideEmptyColumns() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
    fullRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
 var data = fullRange.getValues(),
    numCol = fullRange.getNumColumns();
 for (var i = 0; i < numCol; i++) {
    var col = data.map(function (v) {
        return v[i];
    })
        .filter(function (d) {
            return d !== '';
        });
    if (col.length == 0) sheet.hideColumns(i + 1);
    }
}
```

As for your own code (only checking row 2), you can probably get it to work like this:

```
function hideEmptyColumns2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
//get the values to those columns
var values = range.getValues();
//go through every column
for (var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    Logger.log(values[0][i])
    //if column value is equal to empty  
    if (values[0][i] == "") {
        //hide that column
        sheet.hideColumns(i + 1);
    }
}
}
```