# Automatically hide columns where column is empty using API script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, show-hide

I am working with multiple Google Sheets with several spreadsheets per file. I need to write an API code that automatically hides ALL columns that have NO DATA in them in the ACTIVE SPREADSHEET ONLY (not in every sheet in that file).

I've been looking at this post: [Hide columns when cell is empty in google script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230873/hide-columns-when-cell-is-empty-in-google-script?newreg=5b648e736a264b2c9966a5931cf479ee) for guidance but haven't succeeded in adapting it for my purposes.

I'd be very grateful for some help as I am a complete novice.

Comment: `but haven't succeeded in adapting it for my purposes.` Would you please be more specific... `haven't succeeded` is not a good description of a problem. Would you also clarify: #1-`automatically`: how do expect that this would be triggered? #2-`in the ACTIVE SPREADSHEET ONLY (not in every sheet in that file)` What do you understand to be the difference between the `ACTIVE SPREADSHEET` Vs `every sheet in that file`?

Comment: You tagged `sorting`. Would you please explain how _sorting_ relates to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

**Hide Columns with no data**

```
function hideEmptyColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const hr = 1;//header row
  [... new Array(sh.getMaxColumns()).keys()].forEach(idx => {
    if (getColumnHeight1(idx + 1, sh, ss) < (hr + 1)) {
      sh.hideColumns(idx + 1);
    }
  });
}

function getColumnHeight1(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()) { rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)